# How to use map instead of list for qabstractproxymodel?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qml

how can use a map property as stored data that inherited by qabstractproxymodel, and using as model in QML views?

```
Repeater{

model: cppMapModel;

delegate:delegateComponent 

}
```

even used it in ListView.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try it should be similar to other data types.

```
#include <QAbstractProxyModel>

calss QAbstractProxyModel{

private:

QAbstractProxyModel cppMapModel;

std::map<std::QAbstractProxyModel, int> map;

};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).